# Associating models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, controllers

I have little knowledge about SQL queries and I am new to ruby on Rails.
This is my question. I have a 2 tables Country and State. A country has many states.
I know that there has to be foreign key in State table that joins to the Country table.
So the query to get all the states in a country would be

```
Select * 
From State 
Where 
State. country = Country. country
And  Country.country = 'XYZ'
```

I need to be able to generate a form for creating a new state, which has a drop down list of countries. While creating a state the User can choose a country to which the state belongs to. This will help me retrieve all the states in a country. I know that I need to use has_many and belongs_to in Country and State Models respectively. But I fail to understand the modifications that are to be made in the controllers and views to be able to get the desired form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch all states belonging to a country in ruby/rails you'd simply call the association on the country model. eg:

```
@my_country = Country.find params[:country]
@states = @my_country.states.all
```

This is how rails associations work. You don't need to make the SQL yourself.

You may also like to look at all the other methods that rails provides for associations here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods

Comment: Sorry for the late response.Thanks a lot

Comment: No probs - you should probably "accept" one of the answers (if it helped you solve the problem). :) You can do that by clicking the "tick" next to the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

First I would like you to read on book regarding ruby then you can proceed to rails.

Recommended Books:
Ruby http://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby
Ruby on Rails http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails

This books will give you an idea how the framework works.

Moving on to your problem. You just need a list of all state and country. Then try putting them in an array of your form:

Example
in the view(the .html.erb file) ----

```
<% @countries = w{USA Japan etc..}%>
<% @state = w{state etc...} %>
<% form_for ..... |f|%>
<% f.select :country, @country.collect{|c| [c,c]} %>
<% f.select :state, @state.collect{|c| [c,c]} %>
<% end %>
```